# Redirect NGINX http to https

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, configuration

I'm using LetsEncrypt on an Nginx server over at my domain memorisemedicine.com.

I added a server block at the end of this 'memorise-frontend.conf' file located in /etc/nginx/sites-available that is supposed to redirect non SSL traffic to SSL (https).

Now when I go visit the site without using https://, I notice that sometimes I am redirected correctly now. But notably in Firefox this isn't working for me & I can still access http:// pages on this domain, which I want to never be possible. Does anybody know what's wrong with my .conf file here? I tried editing the nginx.conf file as well, but it seems like it doesn't take server blocks well.

```
server {
charset utf-8;
client_max_body_size 128M;

listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
#listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6



server_name memorisemedicine.com www.memorisemedicine.com;


root        /srv/memorise/frontend/web;
index       index.php;



# access_log  /path/to/basic/log/access.log;
# error_log   /path/to/basic/log/error.log;

location / {
    # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
#location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
#    try_files $uri =404;
#}
#error_page 404 /404.html;

# deny accessing php files for the /assets directory
location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~* /\. {
    deny all;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/memorisemedicine.com/fullchain.pem; # man$
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/memorisemedicine.com/privkey.pem; # m$
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

 }

 server {
 return 301 https://memorisemedicine.com$request_uri;
 }
```

Comment: Your main server block is listening on ports 80 and 443 - you should move the `listen 80` to the other server block.

Comment: Hey Richard, thanks for the help. You're right I found a couple instances of 'listen' used with 443, and I've removed those server blocks as they weren't necessary anyways. It seems like I'm still not being redirected to the SSL version of the site..

Comment: Coming back I think I know what you mean - I added `listen 80;` to make the entire line `server {
listen 80;
return 301 https://memorisemedicine.com$request_uri;
}` and it's still not redirecting. My normal http traffic should all be coming in through 80

Comment: Questions regarding Nginx and other server related software might get better answers on the SO sister site, serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx configuration i can not see the server part which listens to port 443 for ssl.
I will add my configuration so you can edit it to your own need:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.example.com-access.log timed;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.example.com-error.log;

    root /var/www/example/html/public;

    server_name api.example.com;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
     }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example/html/public/index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.example.com-access.log timed;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.example.com-error.log;

    root /var/www/example/html/public;

    server_name api.example.com;

    include snippets/ssl-api.example.com.conf; 
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example/html/public/index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

}
```

My include snippets/ssl-api.example.com.conf;  includes the *fullchain* and *private* from *certbot*.